# Anchor links only work once

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a site with several anchor links. However, they only work once.

When I click a second time and try to navigate to another section of the page, it doesn't work. I use [Trevor Davis' onePageNav jQuery Plugin](http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) on my site. Any suggestions?

My navigation menu (sticky header):

```
<header id="nav" id="home">
    <nav>
        <a href="#folio" class="menu-links">work</a>
        <a href="#aboutme" class="menu-links">about</a> 
        <a href="#home" class="logo"><img src="img/niebel-logo.svg"></a>
        <a href="#contactme" class="menu-links">contact me</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

One of my sections below:

```
<section class="portfolio" id="folio">
    <div class="portfolioText">    
        <h3>Work</h3>
        <h4>Selected Projects</h4>

        <div class="portfolioGallery clearfix">             
        <a href="#" class="portfolioItem"><img src="img/gigteaser.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="portfolioItem"><img src="img/gigteaser.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="portfolioItem"><img src="img/gigteaser.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="portfolioItem"><img src="img/gigteaser.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="portfolioItem"><img src="img/gigteaser.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" class="portfolioItem"><img src="img/gigteaser.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: First check: Any errors in the console? Second: Can you replicate it somewhere where we can check? http://jsbin.com?

Comment: Or you can try JSFiddle.com

Comment: @ChrisG Not so good buddy. There are reasons like, it injects hidden resets, etc.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Really? I always thought it was good. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ChrisG Yes... They are good. They are pioneers, but comparing to jsbin, which I hated first, now jsFiddle is what I hate.

Comment: @ChrisG Approved your suggestion! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Thanks for both! :)